# Implement custom formula in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Can you please help implement the below formula in SQL Server? I am puzzled now.

Here's the table:

```
| Row Number | Column Number L | Column  Number M |    Colum Number Z     |                     Formula                 |

|        117 | 11.98           | 12.34141         | 0.3614100028772230000 |   L117*(Z117)                               |
|        368 | 14.3            | 14.789574        | 0.056470999155824700  | L368*(Z368)-((M117-L117)*(M368/M117))       |
|        620 | 13.45           | 14.034546        | 0.119965883942196000  | L620*(Z620)-((M368-L368)*(M620/M368))       |
|        869 | 15.78           | 16.731183        | 0.254320519446635000  | L869*(Z869)-((M620-L620)*(M869/M620))       |
|       1125 | 20.4            | 22.690612        | 1.000629762258830000  | L1125*(Z1125)-((M869-L869)*(M1125/M869))    |
|       1376 | 20.85           | 25.478565        | 2.056509721684180000  | L1376*(Z1376)-((M1125-L1125)*(M1376/M1125)) |
+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: use `case` expressions

Comment: It makes no sense how the tables are represented to do this. I would suggest using excel as this looks more like a spreadsheet than a table to me.

Comment: Correct I have copied from Spreadsheet but I have to implement the logic in SQL which I m puzzled because I am pulling the data from tables.

Comment: Storing formulas like this is very problematic in any database. This is because it is designed to store data not calculate complex formulas that are stored as data. To do this you will have to utilize dynamic sql to calculate the values. I have seen this done and it is not pretty.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to be using SQL Server 2012+ you can use `LAG` to help you get the values you need for your calculations.

Since the first row is different from the rest, you can use a case statement to get it's value and the others separate.

**Test Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Row] int, [L] int, [M] int, [Z] float)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Row], [L], [M], [Z])
VALUES
    (117, 11.98, 12.34141, 0.3614100028772230000),
    (368, 14.3, 14.789574, 0.056470999155824700),
    (620, 13.45, 14.034546, 0.119965883942196000),
    (869, 15.78, 16.731183, 0.254320519446635000),
    (1125, 20.4, 22.690612, 1.000629762258830000),
    (1376, 20.85, 25.478565, 2.056509721684180000)
;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    [Row],
    L,
    M,
    Z,
    CASE WHEN t.Rn = 1 THEN L * Z 
    ELSE L * Z - ((PrevM-PrevL) * (M/PrevM)) END Formula
 FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Row]) Rn,
        LAG(L) OVER (ORDER BY [Row]) PrevL,
        LAG(M) OVER (ORDER BY [Row]) PrevM,
        LAG(Z) OVER (ORDER BY [Row]) PrevZ
    FROM Table1
) t
```

For **SQL 2008**, you could use sub queries and ROW_NUMBER to get the same result.

```
SELECT
    curr.[Row],
    curr.L,
    curr.M,
    curr.Z,
    CASE WHEN curr.Rn = 1 THEN curr.L * curr.Z 
    ELSE curr.L * curr.Z - ((prev.M-prev.L) * (curr.M/prev.M)) END Formula
 FROM
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Row]) Rn FROM Table1)  curr
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Row]) + 1 Rn FROM Table1) prev ON curr.Rn = prev.Rn
```